# Emit first element on another thread in RxJava

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java2

Good time of day everyone.

I wonder if it's possible to somehow emit element of a Flowable on a different thread than next ones.
For example I have a hot in-memory cache of database objects and I don't want to go to io thread to get elements from there.
Whant I want to do is basically:

```
    if (cache.contains(e)) {
        emiter.emit(cache.get(e));
    } else {
        Io.post(() -> emiter.emit(db.get(e)));
    }
```

I need the same Flowable to use different threads.
I haven't found a way to do this so far.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Consider following method:

```
private Flowable<String> getDbOnlyIfNotCached(String key) {
    if (cache.contains(key)) {
        return Flowable.just(cache.get(key));
    } else {
        return Flowable.fromCallable(() -> db.get(key))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}
```

If `cache.contains(key)` is true, everything will run in the calling thread. If the value is not cached, `db.get(key)` will be called using the io scheduler.

Update: Examples in Android

You can use above method like this:

```
getDbOnlyIfNotCached("hit")
        .subscribe(s ->  {
            // If "hit" is cached, this will be executed in the current thread.
            Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }); 

getDbOnlyIfNotCached("miss")
        .subscribe(s -> {
            // If "miss" is cached, this will be executed in another thread.
            Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
```

Or you can use it in a Flowable chain using `flatMap`.

```
Flowable.just("hello")
        ./* some other operators */
        .flatMap(s -> getDbOnlyIfNotCached(s))
        // If "hit" is cached, chain still runs in the current thread.
        .subscribe(s -> {
            Log.d(TAG, s + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());         
        });


Flowable.just("miss")
        ./* some other operators */
        .flatMap(s -> getDbOnlyIfNotCached(s))
        // If "miss" is cached, chain switches to another thread.
        .subscribe(s -> {
            Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
```

If you want to observe on the main thread, then specify `observeOn` at the end of the chain.

```
Flowable.just("miss")
        ./* some other operators */
        .flatMap(s -> getDbOnlyIfNotCached(s))
        // if "miss" is cached, chain switches to another thread.
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        // Now switched to the main thread.
        .subscribe(s -> {
            Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I want. I need the same Flowable to use different threads.

Comment: @s0nicYouth, I added some example codes in the example. You can insert `getDbOnlyIfNotCached` in any `Flowable` chain using the `flatMap` operator. If this is still not what you wanted, can you update your question with more specific use cases?